# Add column with row number

Tags: sql, rows

I want to add a column to my select showing a set of number from say 1 to 4.

Example:
Select * gives me

```
Id Transaction 
1  10
2  11
3  12
4  13
5  14
6  15
```

I want to add a column called "Flow". The result should be like this.

```
Id Transaction  Flow  
1   10             1 
2   11             2 
3   12             3 
4   13             4 
5   14             1 
6   15             2
```

In this example the flow is from 1-4. Could be 1-n.
No particular relation between Id and Flow is needed.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Use modulo function. Flow = ID mod n.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server or other DBMS that allows `ROW_NUMBER`, you could do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl(Id INT, [Transaction] INT);
INSERT INTO #Tbl VALUES
(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, 13), (5, 14), (6, 15);

DECLARE @N INT = 4;

SELECT *,
    Flow = 1 + ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) - 1) % @N)
FROM #Tbl

DROP TABLE #Tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mySql`.

**Query**

```
set @r := 0;
select Id, `Transaction`,
@r := (@r % 4) + 1 as Flow
from your_table_name
order by Id;
```

## [**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a82b0/1)

### **EDIT**

Following sql query can be used irrespective of rdbms.

**Query**

```
select *, (
    select ((count(*) - 1) % 4) + 1 as Flow
    from your_table_name t2
    where t1.Id >= t2.Id
) as Flow
from your_table_name t1;
```